# How to create a void function in Assembly?

Tags: assembly

In Assembly, if a function returns a value, this value is usually placed in the `eax` register, but what if a function does not return a value (void function), should I not place any value in the `eax` register, or should I just place a 0?

Comment: Be careful, on x86-64 it is `rax`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not place any value. Even if you do the caller won't know about it anyway.